# How create custom checkbox with background using Styled Components?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I've create checkbox with background, but when checkbox is active you **can't uncheck it clicking on icon**. You can uncheck only clicking Label text and I can't figure out what is wrong with

### [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/building-a-checkbox-component-with-react-and-styled-components-93gyw)

Comment: If you used the label to create a custom checkbox from a pseudo, it would work without javascript. . You need to link the label with the input via for/id .input can be anywhere else and hidden in the document flow. here is an exemple : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/NWNqBMp . Reminder about the label use and role : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label ;) From a clean and simple code, it works much easier and lets less side effects appear

Comment: `<label><div class="sc-bdVaJa hbGCZo"><input type="checkbox" class="sc-bwzfXH eKbAYW"><label for=".sc-bwzfXH" class="sc-htpNat giviEY"></label><div class="sc-bxivhb dSZONO"></div></div><span style="margin-left: 10px;">Label Text</span></label>`is the code generated in your codesandbox :(

Comment: The problems is I'm using styled-components, not code generator. It's app-orientiered CSS-in-JS. So, I'm writing code in CSS-in-JS and you give me examples of clear CSS which not completely works like CSS-in-JS

Comment: you can create via js/php/any programming language a proper markup. It will become a must once you'll be tired loosing time crowling through your code(or someone's else) when another bug or update shows up ;)  For fun, it doesn't matter, for a compagny it's money ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because your label is blocking the clicking event, try adding

```
pointer-events: none;
```

to your Label component